# How to calculate service uptime/downtime duration in Grafana/Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm working on a Grafana dashboard to monitor some of our services' uptime/downtime. The metric I used is called `service_status` which could be only 0 or 1 (0 means the service is down and 1 means service is up). The prometheus scrapping interval is set to 1m.

What I need is to calculate the service status duration for each service. if the service is currently up, it will show how long it has been up since last failure. Vice versa if the service is currently down. It will look like this:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej1LW.png)

The way I can think of right now is to use idelta() function to find last time service_status changes. Then I can subtract its time with current time to find the duration based on current service_status via using a if else statement. But my solution does not returning data sometimes and I don't know what's wrong.

```
time() - max_over_time(timestamp(idelta(service_status{service ="serviceA"}[2m]) >0)[30d:1m]) and on() (service_status >0) 

or on() max_over_time(timestamp(idelta(service_status{service ="serviceA"}[2m])<0)[30d:1m]) - time()
```

Could someone tell me how I can calculate the duration for the service_status or help me with my promql query? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure why do you think you need `idelta`. Was this some form of dealing with resolution of subquery?

Comment: @markalex my idea is to first find the timestamp when service_status changed last time. If I understand it correctly, idelta() returns the difference between last two samples. Since the our Prometheus scrapping interval is 1 min, idelta(service_status[2m]) will always include two samples So if idelta(service_status[2m])<0 that means this service went from 1 to 0 and the service went down at that time. And if idelta(service_status[2m]) >0, that means this service recovered from 0 and get back online. Then I can subtract that timestamp from current timestamp to get the duration.

Comment: Seems redundant. `idelta(service_status{service ="serviceA"}[2m]) >0` for your case should be equivalent to `service_status{service ="serviceA"} == 0`

Comment: hi @markalex, you're right on this. I don't need to use `idelta()` to find nearest timestamp for `service_status` change (from 0 to 1). Do you have any ideas other than `idelta()` to find the nearest timestamp when service_status change from 1 to 0 ?

Comment: You general approach was correct: `max_over_time(timestamp(service_status{service ="serviceA"}==0)[30d:1m])` will get you last time service was unavailable (and `==1` for otherwise)